# Can't access BeagleBone through ssh after changing network settings. Need a way to recover or correct the problem

Tags: networking, ssh, beagleboard

BeagleBone is connected through Ethernet. Trying to enable wireless connectivity as well, after plugging a WiFi USB dongle. MiniHDMI port is remapped so cannot be used. The only way to access the BeagleBone is through ssh. For some reason that I cannot understand (greatly appreciated if you explain that to me), after changing the `/etc/network/interfaces` from:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp #static
```

I cannot ssh to my BeagleBone anymore. I can see from a computer connected to the same network (through `arp -a`) as well from my router configuration page, that the BeagleBone never gets an IP from any of the two interfaces. Any ideas on why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is how I solved this.

First of all, it seems that the interfaces configuration file does **not** accept inline comments and that caused the problem in the first place. I still cannot understand how this could actually affect both interfaces.

Second, and most important, in order to regain access to the BeagleBone, do the following:

1. Create a bootable microSD with Ubuntu. This was the same that I used to install Ubuntu on the BeagleBone in the first place.
2. Plug an ethernet cable from BeagleBone to your router/computer.
3. Hold down the BootSD button (located at the far left corner, assuming that you hold the board with the ports towards your body) and power up the board, while holding down the button.
4. After 30" you can release the button. Now you have booted from the operating system on the microSD.
5. All you have to do is:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p2 /mnt
   ```

   Now your filesystem form the MMC is loaded in the `/mnt`. For me it proved that `mmcblk1p2` was where my filesystem was located on the BeagleBone. If that does not work as expected, try the rest of the entries `/dev/mmc*`, until you find the right one.
6. From `/mnt` you can edit, delete, restore, etc files that are in the BeagleBone. In my case, I corrected the `/etc/network/interfaces`.
7. Unmount and shutdown:

   ```
   cd 
   sudo umount /mnt
   sudo shutdown now -h
   ```
8. Remove the microSD and start your BeagleBone normally and enjoy not having to reflash!

Comment: You do realize that "far left corner" is entirely relative, yes?

Comment: ha, sorry for that. I was actually holding the board when I wrote that. It is assumed that you hold the board with the ports towards your body. Answer has been update. Thanks!